# Alternatives to the ++ post-increment operator?

Tags: swift, post-increment

I'd like to refactor this merge sort without using the legacy ++ in Swift.

When unary operators are used in more complex statements using instance methods and multiple levels I have trouble with the logic.

You cannot simply switch `++` to `+=1` because you'll get a `Cannot subscript a value of type '[Int]' with an index of type '()'` error.

So should I be creating a new mutable copy var and then incrementing that var? Also can I refactor this block using guard even though there is no error checking? Pointless?

```
if (hidariCount < hidari.count && (migiCount >= migi.count || hidari[hidariCount] <= migi[migiCount])) {
    sortedArray.append(hidari[hidariCount++])
} else if (migiCount < migi.count && (hidariCount >= hidari.count || migi[migiCount] < hidari[hidariCount])) {
    sortedArray.append(migi[migiCount++])
}
```

Comment: It's interesting to see the mixture of Japanese and English in your variable names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What does the post-increment operator do?

This code

```
hidari[hidariCount++]
```

does 2 things in the following order:

1. the **current value** of `hidariCount` is **used** to access the `hidary` array
2. `hidariCount` is **increased** by `1`

### Solution

So you can refactor your code by replacing this

```
sortedArray.append(hidari[hidariCount++])
```

with this

```
sortedArray.append(hidari[hidariCount])
hidariCount += 1
```

And don't forget to do the same into the `else` branch.

Comment: This is the most succinct answer I have ever received. Thank you. I will now stalk you on SO.

Comment: Hey, I got you to the 10K mark. Congratulations :)  I shall now receive 5% of your income from your new job you'll get with 10K :)

Answer (score 6):

**If** you really really miss them, you can simply define them back in

```
postfix operator ++ // i++
postfix func ++ ( left: inout Int) -> Int {
   defer {left += 1}
   return left
}
postfix operator -- // i--
postfix func -- ( left: inout Int) -> Int {
   defer {left -= 1}
   return left
}
prefix operator ++ // ++i
prefix func ++ ( right: inout Int) -> Int {
   right += 1
   return right
}
prefix operator -- // --i
prefix func -- ( right: inout Int) -> Int {
   right -= 1
   return right
}
```

This is not really advisable though!

Comment: Why not? The use of pre/post increment operators are very clear with some practice. To remove a feature that is very well used in languages such as C and C++, just because one person has an issue with it seems draconian. No one is forced to use a language feature that may seem "confusing", especially compared to the many complexities in the Swift Programming Language. If it works for you, then use it, otherwise, don't. I appreciate this post and made some minor edits to handle compiler warnings.